# Save Spark Dataframe Before Writing to Snowflake

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, lazy-evaluation

I am working in PySpark and I do a bunch of transformations and apply user defined functions before getting a final output table that I am writing to Snowflake. The final command to write to Snowflake takes ~25 minutes to run because it is also performing all the calculations since Spark evaluates lazily and isn't evaluating until that final call.
I want to have the final table evaluated in the step before so I can time how long all the transforms take and then separately time how long the write to Snowflake step takes. How do I separate the two? I have tried to do:

```
temp = final_df.show() 

temp.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions2) \
.option("dbtable","TEST_SPARK").save()
```

But I get error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

And with collect()

```
temp = final_df.collect() 

temp.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions2) \
.option("dbtable","TEST_SPARK").save()
```

But I get error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'write'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `temp` dataframe is having result of **`.show()`** that results none type for temp variable and only `dataframe` has `.write` method to sources.

**`Try with below code:`**

```
temp = final_df
#view records from temp dataframe
temp.show()

temp.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions2) \
.option("dbtable","TEST_SPARK").save()
```

---

```
#collect collects the data as list and stores into temp variable
temp = final_df.collect() 

#list attributes doesn't have .write method
final_df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions2) \
.option("dbtable","TEST_SPARK").save()
```

**`Update:`**

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
#code until show()
temp = final_df
#view records from temp dataframe
temp.show()
end_time = time.time()
print("Total execution time for action: {} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))

start_time_sfw = time.time()
#code until show()
final_df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).options(**sfOptions2) \
.option("dbtable","TEST_SPARK").save()
end_time_sfw = time.time()
print("Total execution time for writing to snowflake: {} seconds".format(end_time_sfw - start_time_sfw))
```

Comment: Good point. But the first one will still result in the .show() step taking ~25 minutes and then again the write step taking ~25 minutes because it is again performing all the evaluation. I want to force evaluation BEFORE writing to Snowflake

Comment: @user3242036, Yes, That's expected behavior from spark `.show()` action triggers all the transformations to execute, to tune your job do `temp=final_df.cache()` then do `temp.show()` now your job won't take 1 time ~25 minutes. to calculate time taken use `time` package. Check my updated answer!

Comment: Thanks. I used the cache() option and it seems to have worked